# Friendly_id gem and its effects on tests (without slug)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, friendly-id

I've implemented friendly_id gem by adding to the User model:

```
include FriendlyId
friendly_id :username
```

In the controller I've added replaced `User.find(params[:id])` with `User.friendly.find(params[:id])`:

```
  def show
    @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])           # Line 21
    redirect_to signup_url and return unless (@user.activated)
  end
```

So I'm not using Slug.

**Problem:** Now suddenly all sorts of tests fail. One example below. I added .to_param as suggested but this didn't change the error message:

```
class AvatarUploadTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    @admin             = users(:michael)
  end

  test "avatar upload" do
    log_in_as("user", @admin.to_param)    # Helper method that logs in.
    get user_path(@admin)                 # Line 16
    ...etc
```

This test uses the following test helper:

```
  def log_in_as(type, user, options = {})
    password    = options[:password]    || 'password'
    remember_me = options[:remember_me] || '1'
    if integration_test?
      post login_path, session: { email:       user.email,
                                  password:    password,
                                  remember_me: remember_me }
    else
      if type == "user"
        session[:user_id] = user.id
      elsif type == "member"
        session[:member_id] = user.id
      end
    end
  end
```

The error message:

```
ERROR["test_avatar_upload", AvatarUploadTest, 2015-04-14 13:46:57 +0000]
 test_avatar_upload#AvatarUploadTest (1429019217.17s)
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:         ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
            app/controllers/users_controller.rb:21:in `show'
            test/integration/avatar_upload_test.rb:16:in `block in <class:AvatarUploadTest>'
        app/controllers/users_controller.rb:21:in `show'
        test/integration/avatar_upload_test.rb:16:in `block in <class:AvatarUploadTest>'
```

How does this relate to the `friendly_id` gem? I don't really understand it and don't know what adjustments I need to make to my tests.

Comment: Paste the full error message, and show the full controller that's triggering the error.

Comment: I added the information and added `.to_param` to the test code as suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I misread your question at first and hadn't realized that you had changed your controller to use `User.friendly.find` - this is unusual because usually you want to use the friendly id for these sorts of URLs.

So, because you're still using the raw `id` then you need to supply that in your test, ie. you need to put:

```
get user_path(@admin.id)
```

If you just provide `@admin` then Rails will call `.to_param` on it, which will be the friendly ID, which would be found if you did: `User.find(params[:id])` but will **not** be found now that you've converted to `User.friendly.find(params[:id])`

Comment: Thanks. I still got the same error on the same line. Should I perhaps also make changes to the test helper that this test uses? I added the test helper to the original post.

Comment: So, my answer didn't solve the error you reported in your question? Ie. _The line `get user_path(@admin)` fails with the error message `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`_

Comment: No, it indeed still gave the same error message on the same line.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I didn't notice that you said you **did** change to use `.friend.find` - let me delete my answer, it's wrong.

Comment: Ok, I edited and undeleted my answer after understanding fully what you've done.

Comment: Yes, changing it to `@admin.id` indeed solved it! Would you say there would be a better implementation? That is, how would you change the controller method to "use the friendly id for these sorts of URLs"?

Comment: You should actually accept my answer if it solved your problem. And yes, generally people leave their controller as-is, so it continues to use `User.find(params[:id])` because they want the URLs to include the slug, not the id.